# How to create a folder in root directory Android

Tags: android

I need to create the **CAT_IMG** folder in the root directory and retrieve it in list view. But the CAT_IMG folder is not creating in the root directory.I added permission in the manifest file. Please help me create a folder in root directory.

```
   private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave) {

        File direct = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG");
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fileName = "fav" + timeStamp + ".JPG";
        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/CAT_IMG");
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        File file = new File(new File("/CAT_IMG"), fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo);
            Log.e("URI", data.getExtras().get("data") + "");

        }
    }
```

Code to retrieve it in list view:

```
private void getImages() {
    String[] filenames = new String[0];
    File path = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG");// add here your folder name
    if (path.exists()) {
        filenames = path.list();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        photos.add(path.getPath() + "/" + filenames[i]);
        Log.e("FAV_Images", photos.get(i));
        Name.add(filenames[i]);
        //Sno.add(i);        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can make a directory in root directory. No permission.

Comment: Its possible to create folder in root directory

Comment: You cannot write to the root of internal storage from an SDK application.

Comment: The above line will create a folder in memory..i checked because if that folder doesn't exist..the folder need to be created.for security purpose am trying to create a folder in root directory...and i created and posted is my code

Answer (score -2):

i created a folder in root directory done small changes in my above code
`

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave) {

        File direct = new File(getFilesDir() + "/CAT_IMG/");
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fileName = "fav" + timeStamp + ".JPG";
        if (!direct.exists()) {
           // File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/CAT_IMG");
            direct.mkdir();
        }

        File file = new File(direct, fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo);
            Log.e("URI", data.getExtras().get("data") + "");

        }
    }`
```

Comment: You are not creating the folder in the root dir you are creating it in your app folder, they are different. More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()  As others said in the comments you can't touch anything in the root folder by default.

Comment: I tried your solution. And it didn't work. It doesn't allow to create folder in root directory as of recent Android versions.